# split string after x characters

Tags: php, split

How to split $string after 5 characters into an array

example:

```
$string="123456789";
```

expected output

```
$output[0] contain "12345";
$output[1] contain "6789";
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With the help of BoltClocks' answer I have created the following function to solve the problem:

```
function split_on($string, $num) {
    $length = strlen($string);
    $output[0] = substr($string, 0, $num);
    $output[1] = substr($string, $num, $length );
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 103):

If you need to split a string after *every* 5 characters, try [`str_split()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php):

```
$output = str_split($string, 5);
```

If you only need to extract the first 5 characters and put the rest of the string in the second part of your array, you can use `substr()` as NullUserException suggests (code from his now-deleted answer):

```
$output[0] = substr($string, 0, 5);
$output[1] = substr($string, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split after 5 characters, try below.

`$first5` splits the string and get the first 5 characters of the `$str` string. `$theRest` splits the string and gets the remaining part of the `$str` string.

```
$first5 = substr($str, 0, 5);
$theRest = substr($str, 5);
```

Variable names are just for explanation. Also if you try this on a string less than 5 characters $theRest will be FALSE