# Linebreak on text to create paragraphs php pdo

Tags: php

Is there a way to line break a certain sentences on the result text on pdo to break them in to two or more paragraphs each results..trying to achieve something like this pic

[image]

While my output was this one

[image]

I tried the answers in similar topic like this one  [Multiple paragraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282144/multiple-paragraphs/30282428#30282428)

using the code similar to

```
$content = $row['content'];
$breakpoint = round($content.length / 2); // half of the string length
$first = substr($content, 0, $breakpoint);
$second = sbustr($content, $breakpoint);
```

But it gives me a "undefined constant length" error Y.Y

my code block to load two results column names "details" and "more_details"

```
<?php  if(isset($_GET['page'])):?>
            <?php foreach($courses as $row):?>

                <h1><?php echo $row['Fullname'];?></h1>
                <?php echo $slug;?>

                <hr><p>
                <?php echo $row['details'];?>
                </p>
                <br>
                <p>
                    <?php echo $row['more_details'];?>
                </p>

            <?php endforeach;?>
```

found an answer thanks to forbs but i'm willing for another method if there would be another way

answer

```
$content = $row['content'];
$breakpoint = round(strlen($content)/ 2); // half of the string length
$first = substr($content, 0, $breakpoint);
$second = substr($content, $breakpoint);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here's the answer for undefined constant length.
That's because content.length is Javascript, and you are in php.

```
$breakpoint = round(strlen($content)/ 2);
```

That should fix it, though that's gotta look very strange to be broken in the middle of a word.

Comment: tried but it gives me "Call to undefined function sbustr()"

Comment: oh yah, substr, not sbustr

Comment: ahaha I didnt notice that typo my mistake.. anyway thanks you help me alot it working fine now though you are right some paragraph broke in the middle well gotta revise the sentences or find another way..btwi put the answer there thanks once again

Comment: Here's a bit of extra help for someone who is polite :)  If you are reading this again `$breakpoint = strpos($content," ",$breakpoint);` will forward it to the nearest word instead of breaking in the middle of one.