# Split String after first character

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a column in a data frame like so:

```
D0.5
A4
C1.3
B2.0
```

I want to be able to split the column so that the first entry (which is always a single character) is separated from the rest of the entry (which is always numeric, but is of different lengths depending on the entry)

I want to do basically exactly this except after the first entry instead of the 5th and in R instead of php.

[split string after x characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200940/split-string-after-x-characters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `substring`

```
x <- c("D0.5", "A4", "C1.3", "B2.0")

substring(x, 1, 1)

[1] "D" "A" "C" "B"
```

To get only the numeric part:

```
as.numeric(substring(x, 2, nchar(x)))

[1] 0.5 4.0 1.3 2.0
```

Or using `stringi`:

```
as.numeric(stringi::stri_sub(x, 2))
```

and using `stringr`:

```
as.numeric(stringr::str_sub(x, 2))
```

For both `stringi` and `stringr`, `2` represents the starting position. You can include the end position if you want to, else it is the last character by default.

Comment: And the numeric part?

Comment: You should extract 0.5 etc, presumably as a number, not a string.

Comment: To add to your solution, you could do something like the following to put it into a data frame: `data.frame(cbind(Letter=str_sub(x, 1, 1), Number=str_sub(x, 2)))` (where `x` is a vector of input).

Comment: @steveb, thanks! But I think it would just be easier to assign individual results in a df or use your suggestion without`cbind`. `cbind` will convert the columns into factors

Comment: @Sumedh Understood.  The following would work better than what I originally suggested: `data.frame(Letter=str_sub(x, 1, 1), Number=as.numeric(str_sub(x, 2)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` (or some variant of this).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub`

```
as.numeric(sub("^.(.*)", "\\1", v1))
#[1] 0.5 4.0 1.3 2.0
```

---

Or

```
library(tidyr)
extract_numeric(v1)
#[1] 0.5 4.0 1.3 2.0
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("D0.5", "A4", "C1.3", "B2.0")
```