# Query Result to Array String

Tags: php, mysql

I Have a simple query :

```
$str = mysqli_query($con,"select no_rekening from tbl_rekening");
While($row= mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
$rek_array .= $row['no_rekening'];
}
echo $rek_array;
```

Result :

> 008-K001008-K002

I want query result convert to array string, like this :

> '008-K001','008-K002'

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200940/split-string-after-x-characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose something like this (sorry I didn't coded in PHP for century)

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rek_array .= $row[$i].',';// append comma after each value you
}
// reassign the value to the variable 
// without final comma 
$rek_array = substr($string,0,-1);
echo $rek_array;
```

I do think it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a comma, then you can just embed that into the string (bear in mind that `$rek_array` is actually a string, not an array):

```
rek_array .= $row['no_rekening'].",";
```

If you want to add those single quote marks too then it's the same idea:

```
rek_array .= "'".$row['no_rekening']."',";
```

Of course that will add a trailing comma at the end, which you may not want - but you could easily [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) that afterwards if you need to.

Comment: but every answer is all correct and can be used.. thx